# Older questions left over

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer, question-lists

In Stack Overflow new questions are focused on a lot even after the OP gets the required answer and marks his question as answered.  Still the question remains at the top of the questions list. The new questions posted and left unanswered are moving off the list and nobody is looking at those questions. So, what I suggest is that answered questions will immediately move out of the questions list. This will reduce confusion, time and helps users to focus on other questions. So rather than answering an answered question, I feel the questions that are left unanswered for more than a day should get some kind of priority to get answered.

From my personal experience I posted [a question for which I didn't receive any answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261991/convert-comment-script-to-shout-box),  and later I posted [the same question with some modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311215/event-without-postback) for which I was answered within minutes. It just depends on the level of experts that are present at the time of posting questions, but when my simple previous question was not answered, I posted the same question later and got the perfect answer. So, please consider this and remove the answered questions from list of recent questions so that unanswered questions will have more chances to get answered.

Answer (score 12):

There is already a list of Unanswered questions (big Unanswered button at the top of the page) for questions that have 0 answers or questions that have answers with 0 total votes on each of them.

The focus on the sites, and there are a lot of features built in to support this, is to create quality questions the FIRST time around.  If you feel that your question is not getting the attention it needs then you should edit the original question to include more detail.  Doing so will bump it back to the top of the recent list and it will be shown on the home page again.

Because of this I don't see the need, nor have the desire, to remove questions that have answers from the views.

Answer (score 3):

One of the things that makes StackOverflow work is the voting system, and peer-review that underlies it.

If questions when off the radar as soon as they are answered, the voting system wouldn't work as effectively, bad answers would not get downvoted, good answers would not get "rewarded" with votes, etc. So I believe your suggestion is counter-productive and would not improve the quality of the site.

Editing your questions brings it back in the spotlight. So consider doing that (improving your question with more details, expanding on what you tried/researched, things like that), and it will get more attention.